# Подскажите, как можно заменить символ в строке на языке C?

Tags: c

Подскажите, как можно заменить символ в строке на языке C? И еще как легче будет сделать. Вывести измененную строку, либо изменения записать в новую строку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char s[] = "foo";
s[0] = 'm';
printf ("%s\n", s);
```